# Trouble accessing files uploaded with Plupload

Tags: php, file-upload, plupload

We are using a multi file uploader plugin and we want to save it to the server using move_uploaded_file() and send mail with direct link of all files after successful upload. We are getting following array...

```
Array
(
    [html5_uploader_0_tmpname] => p15rkfr6oogdt1ln91t0r4obrrh3.jpg
    [html5_uploader_0_name] => show_041.jpg
    [html5_uploader_0_status] => done
    [html5_uploader_1_tmpname] => p15rkfr8mb1plfu4q1giu3v01jl74.jpg
    [html5_uploader_1_name] => 23.jpg
    [html5_uploader_1_status] => done
    [html5_uploader_count] => 2
)
```

And we are using following code...

```
    $("#html5_uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5',
    url : 'upload.php',
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    chunk_size : '1mb',
    unique_names : true,
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
    ],

    // Resize images on clientside if we can
    //resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90}
});
```

}

so the problem is what should we pass at place of $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] and $_FILES["file"]["name"]  in case of this array.

Comment: I don't see anything multidimensional about that.

Comment: @BoltClock: The `$_FILES` array becomes abusively, stupidly multidimensional when there are multiple uploads, though clearly the posted array isn't `$_FILES`.

Comment: @seoppc, I think you forgot to tell us exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Charles we want to save it server using move_uploaded_file(), and how can we do that using this type of array?

Comment: @seoppc, can we see the code you have right now for this, and can you explain what in that code is going wrong?  (Please edit it into your question.)

Comment: @Charles check question again.

Comment: I've updated the title and tagging on this question to hopefully attract more helpful attention.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the updated post.

When there are multiple file uploads in a single form *that share an array-formatted element name*, `$_FILES` gets all wonky.  Instead of adding another layer between the form element name and the file information, [it adds another layer after the file information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

It might be better to visualize it:

```
array(
    'name' => array(
        0 => 'foo.gif',
        1 => 'bar.jpeg'
    ),
    'tmp_name' => array(
        0 => '/tmp/something',
        1 => '/tmp/else',
    )
);
```

Not what you expected, right?

Now, your code is doing something *utterly* nonsensical.  You're looping over `$_POST`, but then you're processing `$_FILES`.  Things don't work that way.

I have *no idea* where you're getting the original array you posted, so I'm going to ignore it.

Let's pretend that `'file'` is the name of the multi-file upload form element and *totally rebuild the `$_FILES` array*:

```
$fixed_files = array();
foreach($_FILES['file'] as $expected => $unexpected) {
    foreach($unexpected as $index => $data)
        $fixed_files[$index][$expected] = $data;
}
```

(This code *can* fail if the inner value is not an array -- see the [multiple upload page in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) for other options to fix `$_FILES`.)

There.  Now we can loop through `$fixed_files` like we should have been able to from the start:

```
foreach($fixed_files as $uploaded) {
    $safe_name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-\.]/', '', $uploaded["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($uploaded["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $safe_name);
    $links[] = "upload/" . $safe_name;
}
```

Note a new addition to your previous code -- `$safe_name`.  The name element of the array *comes from the user* and should not be trusted.  The regex strips out anything other than letters, numbers, dashes, underscores and periods.

**You should also be doing more verification of the uploaded data, if you can!**  For example, if you are expecting images, you should attempt to verify that the files are indeed images.  If you're using PHP 5.3, check out [`finfo_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).  You can use it to retrieve the file's MIME type, and make sure it's a file type you can work with.

Comment: @charles thanks for provided code, but i think this would not solve our issue, our mutlple file uploader sends array as i have posted above. So we want a pay to get each value for move_uploaded_file

Comment: @seoppc, could you get a `print_r($_FILES)`, and edit your original question with the output?  I find it unlikely that your *Javascript upload widget* would change anything in PHP.  It looks like you're using Plupload, which has absolutely zero PHP code whatsoever.  I expect that the raw `$_FILES` is as I've described above.  I know this because I also use Plupload.  :)

Comment: @Charles yes i am using plupload. can you provide me uploading code for plupload

Comment: @seoppc, once again, **could you get a `print_r($_FILES)`, and edit your original question with the output?**  Thank you.

Comment: @charles i have tried yours code and its giving error 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/upload/up.php on line 5

Comment: @charles print_r($_FILES) is blank.

Comment: Then you're working with the wrong file.  You should be modifying the PHP script called by the [`url` configuration parameter](http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php), which is where files get uploaded to, **one at a time**.  I knew something didn't smell right.  You'll never get the funny `$_FILES` nesting behavior with Plupload unless you're doing something equally as funny.

Comment: @charles this is form markup <form method="post" action="upload.php">  thanks for your support.

Comment: @seoppc, I think that's where your trouble is.  `upload.php` is being used both as the behind-the-scenes, *upload-button-clicked* target **and** the *form-submit-clicked* target.  `upload.php` will have a populated `$_FILES` array when it's getting an upload, but **won't** have a populated `$_FILES` array when the form is submitted, because Plupload uploads the files when the upload button is clicked, not when the form is submitted.  (continued)

Comment: Consider using *two* scripts -- one to handle the actual upload of the files, then another to handle the form submit.  You can return data (html, json, whatever) from the upload handler script and update the form contents with appropriate information, so that the form submit handler can do whatever you need it to do.  (continued)

Comment: Please take a look at [the Custom Uploader example](http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php), and the `bind` watching for `FileUploaded` -- the response from the uploader script will be in the third parameter to the callback, not shown in that example.

Comment: @charles i would be happy and if possible can you provide me js and php code to upload files to server.That will make all things clear.

Comment: @seoppc, **I will not write your code for you**.  The code I have written so far and the *links to the examples* provided in my comments should be sufficient to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The output you receive after posting is stored in $_POST which is where the array you are displaying has come from.

In order to make better use of the $_POST Array output, you will firstly need to change the Form Posts output into a multidimensional Array/Output.

The way i did this was by changing where the plupload .js file constructs the html form into a multipart form. Using the following PHP method [multiple upload page in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) as @Charles mentioned.

An example of the lines I edited below using the '[]' brackets around the count and the name of the value in the "name" tags which splits the $_POST data up into a multidimensional array.

```
    if (file.target_name) {
    inputHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="' + id + '[' + inputCount + '][tmpname]" value="' + plupload.xmlEncode(file.target_name) + '" />';
    }
    
    inputHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="' + id + '[' + inputCount + '][name]" value="' + plupload.xmlEncode(file.name) + '" />';
    inputHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="' + id + '[' + inputCount + '][status]" value="' + (file.status == plupload.DONE ? 'done' : 'failed') + '" />';
```

Which turns this:

```
Array
(
    [html5_uploader_0_tmpname] => p15rkfr6oogdt1ln91t0r4obrrh3.jpg
    [html5_uploader_0_name] => show_041.jpg
    [html5_uploader_0_status] => done
    [html5_uploader_1_tmpname] => p15rkfr8mb1plfu4q1giu3v01jl74.jpg
    [html5_uploader_1_name] => 23.jpg
    [html5_uploader_1_status] => done
    [html5_uploader_count] => 2
)
```

Into this:

```
array
  'uploader' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'tmpname' => string 'p15rkfr6oogdt1ln91t0r4obrrh3.jpg'
          'name' => string 'show_041.jpg'
          'status' => string 'done'
      'count' => string '1'
```

Then you can use location of where Plupload saves the temporary (tmp) files found in 'Upload.php' along with the tmpname `$_POST['tmpname']` to move the file.

```
    $targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
    move_uploaded_file($targetDir . $_POST['tmpname'], $destination);
```

Comment: Hope this helps anyone using Plupload as this was quite frustrating for me